# Точно ли feeds не помогает от заморозки чата?

Tags: поддержка, чат, заморозка-чата

Один участник сказал в чате, что сообщения от feeds не спасают от заморозки чата. Так ли это? А как на счёт SmokeDetector? В [faq чата](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) на этот счёт вроде ничего нет.

**P.S:** Я имею в виду **НЕ** главный чат ruSO, и **НЕ** комнату с <s>ping-pong спамом</s> мета-вопросами.

Comment: SmokeDetector считается реальным участником, так что его сообщения будут «спасать» от заморозки чата.

Answer (score 1):

Да, точно. Я делал такой чат и он замораживался.

Comment: Пример можно? ‮